# How to add default text that clears on focus with jQuery to a search form text field in Drupal

Tags: forms, javascript

I would like to have a default text in an Exposed Views Search form that says something like 'type in a keyword to search' which will disappear if the user clicks on the text field and reappear if the user removes the cursor and didn't type anything. I would like the title of the field which is added through Views to become the text in the text field box. Should I use pure jQuery to add the text to the box? Or should I use hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() to add the jQuery and change the location of the title?

Answer (score 9):

You can do this by implementing `hook_form_alter()` in a custom module.

```
function custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if ($form['#id'] == 'search-block-form') {  
        $search_text = 'Your search text here';
        $form['search_block_form']['#default_value'] = $search_text;
        $form['search_block_form']['#attributes'] = array(
        'onfocus' => "if (this.value == '$search_text') {this.value = '';}",
        'onblur' => "if (this.value == '') {this.value = '$search_text';}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Now it is searching for 'Your search text here' when landing on the search page. With Views Exposed filters setting the default value doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is the both, [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) like this, you can add the `placeholder`attribute for fallback.

And after, for browsers that don't understand placeholder, you can use pure jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, because the way Views Exposed filters is structured setting the default attribute also sets the filter which is rendered later. Using the [jQuery Input Example plugin](https://github.com/mudge/jquery_example) I added some custom code to a helper module.

First, I need to add the jQuery to the page. Since I think I might use this in the admin theme also I didn't put it in a theme so it gets added to the overlay.

```
function helper_preprocess_page (&$vars) {
  // Let's add some js to page for the search box.
  $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'helper');
  drupal_add_js($path . '/js/jquery.example.min.js');
  drupal_add_js($path . '/js/helper.js');
}
```

In the helper.js file I added the code to execute the helper plugin.

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.helper =  {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      $('input#edit-search-job-aggregation').example('Enter a location (optional)'); 
      $('input#edit-search-api-views-fulltext').example('Enter a keyword (optional)');   
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```