# Text inside Search box

Tags: theming, search

How could I add a default text inside drupal's search box? I have done this with jquery but I need the text to be translated.

I know this can be done with the [Custom Search](http://drupal.org/project/custom_search) module but it is a little overkill to add a module for such a small feature. Hopefully this can be achieved using my theme's preprocess function. Any ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: Related: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10652/how-to-add-default-text-that-clears-on-focus-with-jquery-to-a-search-form-text-f

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Drupal to communicate a translated string to Javascript:

```
drupal_add_js(array('my_string' => t('Default Text')), 'setting');
```

Then, have your jQuery read the value:

```
var str = Drupal.settings.my_string;
```