# How to add default text that clears on focus to a form in Drupal?

Tags: forms

I would like to display a default text in a field of a views filter form. That default text would then be hidden "on focus", and would re-appear "on blur".
So far I have tried to follow the instructions given here:
[How to add default text that clears on focus with jQuery to a search form text field in Drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10652/how-to-add-default-text-that-clears-on-focus-with-jquery-to-a-search-form-text-f)
but with no success.

What I did:

**1.** Downloaded the Jquery files (https://github.com/mudge/jquery_example/downloads), and copied them in my /sites/all/libraries/mudge-jquery directory

**2.** Added a helper.js file into that directory with that code

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.helper =  {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      $('input#edit-title.form-text.beautytips-module-processed.bt-active').example('TEXT TO HELP'); 
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

**3.** Created a simple module with that code:

```
function helper_preprocess_page (&$vars) {
  // Let's add some js to page for the search box.
  $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'helper');
  drupal_add_js($path . '/sites/all/libraries/mudge-jquery/jquery.example.min.js');
  drupal_add_js($path . '/sites/all/libraries/mudge-jquery/helper.js');
}
```

Still nothing is displayed in my "input#edit-title.form-text.beautytips-module-processed.bt-active" field. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is your doctype HTML5 or (X)HTML? Oh and we'll need to see the code in jquery.example.min.js to help out really

Answer (score 2):

What you want here is:-

a) hook_form_alter to change the form

b) #attached to add JS to the form

c) add clear-text to `['#attributes']['classes']` where necessary.

Then you can use [this](http://snipplr.com/view/18464/) little JS.

```
 Drupal.behaviors.clearText = function(context) {
    var inputs = $('input.clear-text:not(.processed)');

    // Store the original values
    inputs.each(function() {
      $this = $(this);
      $this.data('default', $this.val());
    }).addClass('processed');

    // Set up inputs to clear on focus & reload default (if blank) on blur
    inputs
      .focus(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        if ( $this.val() == $this.data('default') ) {
          $this.val('');
        }
      })
      .blur(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        if ( $this.val() == '' ) {
          $this.val( $this.data('default') );
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: When you see something new, it's always helpful to search core for that. In this case, there are hundreds of examples, here is one: `$form['#attached']['js'][] = drupal_get_path('module', 'field_ui') . '/field_ui.js'`

Answer (score 1):

i have used a little javascript to display default text which gets removed on focus. 
However in validation i have to check for null if the field is blank and as well as the default text.

```
 $form['account details']['first name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('First Name'),
    '#default_value' => t('Be sure of your first name'),
    '#attributes' => array(
    'onblur' => "if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Be sure of your first name'}",
    'onfocus' => "if (this.value == 'Be sure of your first name') {this.value = ''}" 
      , ),  
       );
```

Comment: Using on* is unseemly, ugly, deprecated etc.

Comment: well am new to it....thanks for telling.your logic uses functions a bit new to me for now . Anyways thanks @chx

Answer (score 0):

I think [Compact Forms](http://drupal.org/project/compact_forms) module will help you. Even if you won't use it as is - you can take js code from that module that will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I use the follow simple straight-forward code for my search fields and add it in my theme:

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.mysiteSearch = {
    attach: function() {
      // Apply the default text to the search block's text field.
      $('#block-search-form .form-text')
      // Add default text options on blur.
      .blur(function () {
        $(this).addClass('gray');
        $(this).attr('value', Drupal.t ('Search...'))
        // keep what's typed
        .keypress(function(){
          $(this).unbind('blur');
        })
        // clear on focus
        .focusin(function () {
          $(this).attr('value', '');
          $(this).removeClass('gray');
          $(this).unbind('focusin');
        });
      })
      // Trigger the blur event to set things up.
      .blur();
    }
  };
}(jQuery));
```

Just be sure to set a .gray css style.