# Adding default text to input field

Tags: hooks

I was needing to add a default value to a text field that disappears when you click on the field.

I did found this question :

[How to add default text that clears on focus to a form in Drupal?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/46096/how-to-add-default-text-that-clears-on-focus-to-a-form-in-drupal)

However, my knowledge is pretty limited as far as creating hooks so I'm a little lost as to the solution being drawup up here.

Could someone please point me in the right direct?

Cheers!

Comment: Sorry but we can't write code for you. And we can't write a complete documentation. If you need basics, see [how to implement a hook?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/99556/16495) or [Examples for Developers](https://drupal.org/project/examples).

Comment: Thanks Molot, I should have mentioned that I did look into implementing a hook - but I'm unsure how this fits into achieving my desired effect.  ie. How do I then link in the JS file.  Cheers (edit: Clive's answers solved it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is 2014 you're probably looking for the [placeholder attribute](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/text#Example_B), and not an old-school javascript solution.

Broad strokes: Implement [`hook_form_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and add the attribute there:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'foo') {
    $form['bar']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Baz');
  }
}
```

Comment: Legend!  Cheers Clive, this is exactly the solution I was looking for.